# What should the converted data type of the corresponding column within the Data Converter SSIS Data Flow Component be?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ssis, etl

We have the plain Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on one of our servers

We decided to create DTSX files on the filesystem so that we can use BIDS 2008 to open the DTSX files

One SSIS Control Flow Components that takes data from around 18-19 columns from a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SQL select query, and then converts the values in order to place them in the Microsoft Access table. I have a number of columns that I retrieve from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 table using a DataFlow Component called OLE DB Source. After retrieving the data, I have a Data Converter data Flow Component that converts the values. Finally, the converted values are placed by an OLE DB Destination data Flow Component, and placed in a Microsoft Access table.

For one of the  columns from a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 , the data type is varchar(5)

The value in the above varchar(5) column  needs to be extracted from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 using a SSIS DataFlow Component called OLE DB Source as a string [DT_STR] Data Type
It needs to converted using the Data Converter SSIS data Flow Component 
Finally, it needs to placed in the Microsoft Access table to a  column of the data type called Text.

What should the converted data type of the corresponding column within the Data Converter SSIS Data Flow Component be?

Comment: What have you tried? This would take maybe 10 minutes in SSIS to throw together a quick test to see what happens....

Comment: Sorry.  I'm really new to Microsoft SSIS technology, and I'm dealing with an existing packages with a lot of column mappings, and a lot of Control Flow Components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vikramsinh-shinde Thanks for the webpage links.  The following implementation seemed to ensure that the SSIS package ran properly, however, I hope it's the proper way to handle conversion in the SSIS packages.

1. -varchar(5) column values in Microsoft SQL Server 2008
2. -extracted as string [DT_STR] that has a length of 5 and Codepage of 1252 within SSIS DataFlow Component called OLE DB Source
3. -converted to Unicode string [DT_WSTR] that has length of 5 ( and non-modifiable codePage of 0 ) within  SSIS Data Flow Component called Data Converter
4. -loaded into Microsoft Access column values of data type called Text

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below resources.

[Integration Services Data Type Mapping](http://milambda.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html)

[Data Type Translations](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations)

[Integration Services Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)