# Access Connection string issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection

i have just produced a simple access connection and a simple DataAdaptor and Dataset to get the relevant information pasted into the gridview.

The only issue i am getting is it says no errors but brings up this message and it does not run properly:

```
"An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'."
```

Here is my code :

```
public partial class Database : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public OleDbConnection cn=new OleDbConnection(@"Data Source =Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\jSte\Desktop\database_1.mdb; Integrated Security=true; User Instance =true");
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter ("SELECT * from CustomerDetails", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `Data Source`s, this should work

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\jSte\Desktop\database_1.mdb; Integrated Security=true; User Instance=true
```

Here are some examples:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

You could also use the [`OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to create your connection-string.

Comment: do i still add the @"Data Source = " before that part?

Comment: @Josh: why do you want to add "Data Source" twice?

Comment: I changed it and it brought up this comment: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."... this was highlighted on the " ad.Fill(ds);" part?

Comment: I don't know that error, but maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589/how-do-i-fix-the-multiple-step-ole-db-operation-errors-in-ssis

Comment: Your article helped me i had the wrong clause at the end of data source had to change it to "Persist Security Info=False;" as i had no security present for this test database. Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong. You have specified the `Data Source` property multiple times. Try this:

```
public OleDbConnection cn=new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\jSte\Desktop\database_1.mdb; Integrated Security=true; User Instance =true");
```

Comment: I changed it and it brought up this comment: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."... this was highlighted on the " ad.Fill(ds);" part?

Comment: That's a different issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply try in this way.

```
public partial class Database : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public OleDbConnection cn=new OleDbConnection(@"
                           Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                           Data Source=C:\Documents and 
                           Settings\jSte\Desktop\database_1.mdb; 
                           Integrated Security=true; User Instance =true; 
                           Persist Security Info=True");  
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from CustomerDetails", cn);
      OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter (cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      ad.Fill(ds);
      GridView1.DataSource = ds;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
 }
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129744/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value) for some more clarification.