# How to open a SQL Server Database in Outlook VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, visual-studio, outlook

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2017, SQL Server Express 2017 and Office 2007.

I created a SQL Server Project in Visual Studio. I can see the Project in my data Folder.

When I try to Open the Database in my Outlook VBA program I get an error
[image]

This is my code, the Data Source details are all copied from the Target Connection String generated in Visual Studio. I added the Provider=SQLOLEDB line as that seemed to be what my searches online indicated it should be.

```vb
Set KA_DB = New ADODB.Connection
Set KA_RS_Leagues = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_Com = New ADODB.Command
KA_DB.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
        "Data Source=GARYSPC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=KADB;" & _
        "Integrated Security=True;" & _
        "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
        "Pooling=False;" & _
        "MultipleActiveResultSets=False;" & _
        "Connect Timeout=60;" & _
        "Encrypt=False;" & _
        "TrustServerCertificate=True"
Set KA_Com.ActiveConnection = KA_DB
```

Comment: Possible duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589/how-do-i-fix-the-multiple-step-ole-db-operation-errors-in-ssis

Answer (score 0):

After dozens of trial & error guesswork this line worked :

KA_DB.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=GARYSPC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=KADB; Trusted_Connection=yes"

It seems that the TrustedConnection=yes was the key ...